# yugabytebd springboot integration

Tags: spring-boot, yugabytedb

I am trying to integrate yugabytedb with springboot application, but when trying to run the application I am getting the attached exception

[Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
com.yugabyte.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultYsqlDataAccessStrategy.<init>(DefaultYsqlDataAccessStrategy.java:49)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.<init>(org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGeneratorSource, org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalMappingContext, org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcConverter, org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations)'
```

The calling method's class, com.yugabyte.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultYsqlDataAccessStrategy, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/Users/shubhankar.ghosh/.m2/repository/com/yugabyte/spring-data-yugabytedb-ysql/2.3.0/spring-data-yugabytedb-ysql-2.3.0.jar!/com/yugabyte/data/jdbc/core/convert/DefaultYsqlDataAccessStrategy.class
```

The called method's class, org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/Users/shubhankar.ghosh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jdbc/2.4.2/spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar!/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/DefaultDataAccessStrategy.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy:][1]
```

Comment: Using incompatible versions. Please add your `pom.xml`/`build.gradle`.

Comment: I am also running into the same issue, using spring-data-yugabytedb-ysql:2.3.0 and jdbc-yugabytedb:42.2.7-yb-5-beta.5, tried with other combinations also and none worked till now.

Comment: By the way, downgrading to spring boot 2.6.x version and using `42.3.5-yb-1` as version of jdbc-yugabytedb fixed the issue.